# Select box : remove borders

Tags: html, select

I have removed the border around the select box.
           select#xyz
        {
           border:0px;
          outline:0px;
           }

But, the border around the drop-down arrow stays. How to remove the border surrounding it?

Comment: if you're note using custom dropdowns, you'll be at the mercy of the client's browser and how it renders the dropdown. As far as I know, browsers render them differently (for instance: mobile (chrome) and desktop).

Comment: what browser do you have this issue with. Is there any other styling in use? Post a working example of your problem.

Comment: @AlexTartan can u plz suggest a custom drop down, without any borders, just text followed by a dropped down arrow.

Comment: @Brino there is nothing else, just this class n select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select#xyz
{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But, this removes the arrow as well. I only want the border around it to go away.

Comment: This is the only way to do what you're asking, you need to remove the browser rendering and style it yourself (add your own arrow etc).

Comment: okay thanks. I have added a down-arrow glyphicon next to select. Any idea  hw to open the select box(display all options) if that down arrow is also clicked. I am not able to think of correct keywords to search for this case.

Comment: You could also look into making a custom select element using HTML, CSS and Javascript so you could have full control over its styling.